# Problem with Multicolumn and Multirow table

Tags: tables, multirow, ieeeconf

I have a problem in my multirow and multicolumn table. As you can see in the figure, there is an extra horizontal line over the first column. Can anybody tell me how to remove it. I constructed the entire table with the help of articles given in Latex WikiBooks.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt, conference]{ieeeconf}  
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts                              
\overrideIEEEmargins      
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}
%-----------------------------------------------%
\begin{table}[!t]   \label{table:accuracy}
\centering
\caption{Title.}
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | c | c |} \cline{1-4}

& \multicolumn{3}{ c| }{A} \\
\hline 

\multicolumn{1}{|p{1cm}|}{\centering A= \\ $[B,C]$} & \multirow{2}{*}{C} & \multirow{2} {*}{D} & \multicolumn{1}{|p{1.5cm}|}{\centering E+ \\ F} & \multicolumn{1}{|p{1.8cm}|} {\centering G+\\+H+I}  \\  
\hline \hline 
$[4,1]$        &    30.22\%  &   46.67\%  &  44.27\%  &  30.48\%   \\
$[4,2]$      &    76.94\%  &   73.27\%  &  80.03\%  &  38.47\%   \\         
$[4,3]$      &    55.22\%  &   68.75\%  &  71.66\%  &  57.29\%   \\         
$[4,4]$      &    98.98\%  &   79.52\%  &  82.59\%  &  21.84\%   \\
$[5,2]$      &    36.94\%  &   56.48\%  &  63.25\%  &  47.40\%   \\     
$[5,3]$      &    63.99\%  &   53.30\%  &  51.70\%  &  59.32\%   \\         
$[5,4]$      &    46.46\%  &   39.06\%  &  39.94\%  &  59.91\%   \\         
$[6,4]$      &    96.80\%  &   96.80\%  &  100\%    &  98.17\%     \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|p{1cm}|}{\centering R \\ S}  &  \multirow{2}{*}{56.37\%} &  \multirow{2}{*}{58.33\%} &  \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{60.15\%}}  &  \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{51.76\%}} \\     
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The top figure shows how it is currently, and how I would like it to be:

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to be a complete document and show the image from _that_ document, your fragment can't be run but presumably doesn't generate that image as `Guided filter` and other text is not shown.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh yes sorry. Done.

Comment: Now it should run as a standalone too. I hope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had the column count incorrect in you `\cline` (also don't use `\label` before `\caption`. I used the standard `article` as I didn't hav ethe conference class you are using

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt, conference]{article}  

\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}


\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}
%-----------------------------------------------%
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Title.}\label{table:accuracy}
\smallskip
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | c | c |} \cline{2-4}

\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}
& \multicolumn{3}{ c| }{A} \\
\hline 

\multicolumn{1}{|p{1cm}|}{\centering A= \\ $[B,C]$} & \multirow{2}{*}{C} & \multirow{2} {*}{D} & \multicolumn{1}{|p{1.5cm}|}{\centering E+ \\ F} & \multicolumn{1}{|p{1.8cm}|} {\centering G+\\+H+I}  \\  
\hline \hline 
$[4,1]$        &    30.22\%  &   46.67\%  &  44.27\%  &  30.48\%   \\
$[4,2]$      &    76.94\%  &   73.27\%  &  80.03\%  &  38.47\%   \\         
$[4,3]$      &    55.22\%  &   68.75\%  &  71.66\%  &  57.29\%   \\         
$[4,4]$      &    98.98\%  &   79.52\%  &  82.59\%  &  21.84\%   \\
$[5,2]$      &    36.94\%  &   56.48\%  &  63.25\%  &  47.40\%   \\     
$[5,3]$      &    63.99\%  &   53.30\%  &  51.70\%  &  59.32\%   \\         
$[5,4]$      &    46.46\%  &   39.06\%  &  39.94\%  &  59.91\%   \\         
$[6,4]$      &    96.80\%  &   96.80\%  &  100\%    &  98.17\%     \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|p{1cm}|}{\centering R \\ S}  &  \multirow{2}{*}{56.37\%} &  \multirow{2}{*}{58.33\%} &  \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{60.15\%}}  &  \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{51.76\%}} \\     
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I had tried this. It was this line: `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}` which made the difference. Could you tell me what this does?

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar it replaces the table default `|c|` template for that cell by `c|` so you get no vertical rule on the left.